# How do i grep finger output with a list of names in a file?

Tags: grep

basically I have a list of friends names in a file. I want to write a script that will use that list of names and grep finger for those names.

Eventually I would like for a new terminal window to open and say something like:

Hey $USER has logged on.

Once That user has logged on I would like the sleeping script to move the friends name to a different list that looks for log out as well.

But right now I am stuck on trying to remember how to have a list of names in a file as my grep search criteria pipe through finger.

Something like

```
finger | grep ? | cut -c 11-25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friends.txt

```
FRIENDS='amy|beth|clara|dale'
```

findfriends.sh

```
source friends.txt 
finger | grep -E $FRIENDS | cut -c 11-25
```

Comment: friends.txt: line 1: amy: command not found
friends.txt: line 2: beth: command not found
friends.txt: line 3: clara: command not found
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
This is the error string I get

Comment: Well, i dont know what i did wrong but i rewrote the script and friends.txt and its working perfect! Not sure what i typed wrong!? But thank you kind soul!